# How to get tab-completion in SublimeREPL: PowerShell?

Tags: powershell, sublimetext

The default `PowerShell` is not convinient to copy/paste command output. SublimeREPL solves this problem very well; however, there's no tab-completion. This made PowerShell hard to use. Is there a way to get the tab-completion?

Comment: I don't know SublimeREPL, but [PSReadLine](https://github.com/lzybkr/PSReadLine) provides CTRL-copy/paste, a shared line buffer, syntax highlighting and multiline editing capabilities while preserving tab-completion

Answer (score 0):

Keyboard shortcuts can differ, based on your configuration and OS.
Have you tried <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>/</kbd>?

Comment: Thank you. I'm using Sublime Text 3 on Windows 7; `Alt-/` doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give this a try? http://dilutedthoughts.com/dilutedthoughts/2012/12/06/adding-powershell-package-in-windows-for-sublime-text-2
 i use sublimetext2, powershell v3 on windows 7 and it works.